# NestJS multiple WebSocketGateway

Tags: sockets, microservices, nestjs

Is it possible to run one NestJS WebSocketGateway several times with different parameters?
Maybe possible to use microservices for this?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible to create as much `WebSocketGateway` as you want. All you need is to register your gateways in `providers` property of your `@Module`. Gateways with same port will use only 1 `socket.io` server instance. When you create gateway with another port, NestJS will create one more server instance and so on.

Comment: What about setting another parameters to the gateway?

Comment: @Morbo I have same question